# principal bundles references

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, principal-bundles, model-categories

I am studying the second chapter of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.00929.pdf) and even though I have a small experience with principal $G$-bundles I am struggling with some theorems that I have not seen so far. Is there a modern approach to this subject so that I can understand the chapter of the pdf? I suppose there should be an approach with model categories (I mean proving results for classifying spaces and principal bundles using model categories).

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you're missing, but generally, you could look up the references made in that chapter.

Comment: Sorry I meant whether there is an approach of studying classifying spaces using model categories or 2-categories.